# In which programming language IOT platform kaa is developed?

Tags: open-source, iot, kaa

I've recently started to work with KaaIoT. I'm wondering in which language kaa's server side is coded..and I would also like to know whether we can customize server side.
Thank You

Comment: It is Java - see https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa. But your question is off-topic, I think you'd better to delete it before it is closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kaa is developed in java. You can check on github [image]